# Create GWT Anchor element with download attribute

Tags: java, html, gwt

I want to create a link element with the html [download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) from my GWT Presenter. Using an UI-Binder is not an option. I tried using an [Anchor](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html) object but could not find an option there. Is it possible without using JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Anchor a = new Anchor("download something", "download.html");
a.getElement().setAttribute("download", "");
```

This will create a link with an empty download attribute.

If you set a value for the attribute, this value will be used as the pre-filled filename in the Save prompt, for example:

```
a.getElement().setAttribute("download", "downloadname.html")
```

Comment: Attributes always have a value. `download` is equivalent to `download=""` when parsed by the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Thomas Broyer. I updated my answer.